# why is '£' changed to 'Â£' in my imported dataset

Tags: sql-server, import

I have just attempted to import data into sql server for the first time and it worked. The only issue was the '£' value in the symbols column changed into 'Â£'. I changed the value back to '£' with the attached code although this isn't ideal for large datasets where i may not notice changes like this.

Please can someone explain why this happened and how to avoid it?

```
numbers symbols colours
5   $   red
1   £   blue
32  !   green
84  *   yellow
16  %   
55  %   orange


UPDATE Pre_Prod.dbo.test_dataset
SET symbols = '£'
WHERE symbols LIKE 'Â£'
```

Comment: Seems like an encode problem when you're importing. You need to show us how you're importing the data, not what you're doing to it *after* the import.

Comment: Usually this means a codepage mismatch between the application and the database.